# add document to a groups one drive usign microsofts graph api

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to find a way to add documents to a group in Office Online via the Microsoft graph api.  I see example in the documentation (http://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/drive) to get items in a groups one drive but no way to post or put documents to a groups one drive.

Answer (score 3):

Group drive contains `root` and `items` navigation properties just like regular drive resource. 
Just like you can create new files on the drive, you should be able to use similar [API](http://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/item_post_children) on group drive as well.

`POST /groups/{group-id}/drive/items/{parent-item-id}/children`.

Note: By default, all navigation properties are read-only, which means that you can't `patch` to the resource and update the navigation property.